# How to grant rights for a user in DB2 Express?

Tags: windows, db2, authorization

I have installed DB2 Express on a PC. My user is not an administrator user, however as far as i know, it is possible to grant a user rights, so he can create/delete/modify a database.

I have executed: `db2set DB2_GRP_LOOKUP=local`
after that i created a Local group: `DB2Admins`, and added myself to it. After that i executed `` `db2 update dbm cfg using sysadm_group db2admins ``.

After that i tried to `create database test`, but i get the error `SQL1092N The requested command or operation failed because the user ID does not have authority to perform the requested command or operation. User ID: "myUserID".`

I created a local user, and added it to the same group. If i log in with this local user, then it is ok. The user can create a a database.
My user however is a domain user, and with that it is not working.

Does anyone has any idee how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you restart the instance after setting the `DB2_GRP_LOOKUP` variable?

Comment: @mustaccio: yes, i executed `db2stop` and then `db2start`

Comment: If you have enabled extended security (which is the default installation option), you may want to try adding your ID to the DB2USERS group.

Comment: @mustaccio: i have added to both local groups, `db2admins` and `db2users` a domain group which includes my usernamte too. i also added my username seperate too, but still not working :(

Comment: Try to set `DIAGLEVEL` to 4, delete `db2diag.log` (you can try `db2diag -A` but I'm not sure this command is available on Windows), run `create db` and check what errors appear in the diagnostic log -- they may give some clue.

Comment: @mustaccio: Thanks for the idee. As i can see there is not much usefull information. What i see is: `function: DB2 UDB, oper system services GetGroupsFromAccessToken, probe: 999. Message: Unable to acquire access token.` Or is there anything else you would need?

Comment: What are the credentials of the login that runs the DB2 service? It needs enough permissions to do the AD lookup. Local Service obviously won't do, for example.

Comment: @mustaccio: Thank you very much!! I never would have thought about that. It is working now. However i have one more question. There are six services, and i only changed the logon credentials for one of them. Should i change for the others too, or it is not required?

Comment: What do you mean by six services? Six DB2 instances, or six different services related to DB2 (don't recall their exact names, there's one related to Java, then DAS, something else...) Only the instances do authentication, so only those need to access the AD.

Comment: @mustaccio - you should post your comments as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DB2 will by default look for the group information in the same directory where the user is defined. For a domain user that would be the domain itself. If a domain user is a member of a local group, after setting `DB2_GRP_LOOKUP=local` make sure to restart the DB2 instance.

If you have enabled extended security (which is the default installation option), you may want to try adding your ID to the `DB2USERS` group.

Since the DB2 instance will need to perform the domain directory lookup when authenticating domain users, the account that runs the DB2 instance service must have sufficient permissions to perform the AD lookup. For example, Local Service authority would not be able to do that.

Each DB2 instance service needs such authority. There are other DB2-related services (DB2 DAS, DB2 Remote Command Server, etc. -- described in http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/r0023249.html) -- they do not perform authentication and therefore do not require domain rights.

Comment: Thank you worked perfectly... the secret sauce for me was that I needed to reconfigure the DB2 service to run as a domain account, never would have thought of that.